# Storing "readonly" object as serialized data in relational DB

Tags: mysql, database, json, database-design, serialization

I was wondering if storing objects as serialized data (example json) in a relational db is ever a good practice. I know it is generally a bad thing, and I'm not planning on using it extensively, but I stumbled on a case which got me thinking.

So, here is my situation. I'm basically building an mobile ordering system for delivering items from point A to point B. A is starting address, B is destination... both are current GPS coordinates of users (alongside with readable data like street name, street number etc).

These are the requirements:

- each order has a starting address
- destination address is optional
- once the order is created and addresses along with it, addresses will never be updated
- each order stores a new set of addresses, meaning if there are more orders from the same address, previously saved address will not be reused
- I don't need any queries on address data, like filtering, sorting ...
- structure of address data if fixed. I know this is where serialization has its advantages, but I will certainly not need it.

So, the dilemma is whether to use a separate table for address data (columns: id, street, street number, lat, lng...), or to simply store addresses as JSON strings?

The only down side with JSON, that I see, is that the data has to be serialized/deserialized. Since it has just a few fields it can't make much of a difference.

On the other hand there are a few things I don't like with separate table:

- it could have millions of rows which are needed only for display purposes
- it is easier to monitor data if everything is in one table
- the data is needed wherever information about the order is displayed, so I would need to join those 2 tables all the time
- highly unlikely, but theoretically, I could run out of autoincremented ids

I guess I can't go much wrong with a standard relational approach and store addresses in a separate table, but I just can't see any real advantage in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you SURE that you will never need to do any queries/analyses on the address data?

If this is for a little personal project, this seems fine.

However, if you ever need to change any properties, especially if this project is not completely dictated by you, it will be a gigantic hassle. I wouldn't worry too much about having "millions of rows used only for display purposes" -- modern database systems are optimized for storing a lot of rows, but not necessarily unstructured data.

So, I would strongly suggest you go with the tried-and-true relational approach.

- **it could have millions of rows which are needed only for display purposes**: If you're concerned about running out of auto incremented IDs, I bet you want to make this some massive delivery service. You really wouldn't want to group by GPS coordinates?
- **it is easier to monitor data if everything is in one table:** I don't think this is true. Obviously, if all of the data is stored in a consistent format, this will be the case. But monitoring data that has JSON that you'll have to process every time seems like another story.
- **the data is needed wherever information about the order is displayed, so I would need to join those 2 tables all the time**: If this is actually slower, fair point. However, if you only join the sub-tables with which you're concerned, I imagine that the joins will run faster than json parsing.
- **highly unlikely, but theoretically, I could run out of auto-incremented ids** : see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707072/what-is-the-biggest-id-number-that-autoincrement-can-produce-in-mysql). Not gonna happen.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I see no purpose in sorting/filtering by gps coordinates or street names. Also I'm sure that the properties will not change. It if was the case I wouldn't event think about serializing. I'm just wondering does the one or the other approach has any real advantages, or it is purely a "religios" thing as Sebas says :)

Comment: It's a "religious" thing for a reason -- it's so much easier to handle when you start getting a lot of data. I think you're fine either way, but I don't think you should consider "ease of writing these join operations" in your calculus. Once you write them once, you're done. If you're really concerned about performance, profile! I would guess that using MySQL the way it was designed would be faster, but I'm obviously not sure. You can even index on the addresses!

Comment: And running out of auto incremented IDs is another issue entirely. By that time, I'm sure you would have many MANY employees, and I'm sure a whole new database design. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707072/what-is-the-biggest-id-number-that-autoincrement-can-produce-in-mysql

Comment: Since there are no arguments supporting the other side, I'll go with your suggestion. Although for all of you "serialization is evil" fanatics, I think this classifies as a perfectly plausible use case for json serialization.

Answer (score 2):

i'd go for the relational option, for the following reasons:

1. I'm religious about data normalization
2. If your json address pattern changes, you don't have to reprocess all your strings. You just add or remove one field from the table, and adapt your crud.

Comment: The address pattern will not change. If it ever theoretically would, it would just add new fields, not change the old ones. Religion is another thing :)