# MySQL ID Column Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that auto increments an `id` column every time an entry is added.  About once per year, I delete all of the data in this table and start new.  Right now, the `id` column's next auto increment value will be 27721.

Questions...

1. For this type of situation, would it be advisable to reset the auto incrementing to 1 when I delete the table data?
2. Does it matter?
3. How high is "too high" for ids like this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707072/what-is-the-biggest-id-number-that-autoincrement-can-produce-in-mysql) can help you decide.

Comment: How high is too high?  For a signed integer, you can start to worry when you hit 2 billion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generally it would not be advisable.  You will break things referencing specific IDs, but mostly because...
2. It doesn't matter.
3. The `auto_increment` limit is the sizes of the column.  If it's an unsigned int, that's in the billions so if you only have 27721 after a couple years it's probably not a concern.

Moreover I would recommend that you not delete the data and just archive it instead.  It would probably make it easier to restore if you had to.