# Reordering database after deleting an element in Django Python

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

Suppose I have 5 elements in my Django model user. Now I have deleted 4th element like this

```
user.objects.filter(id=4).delete()
```

Now The ID's after deleting will be 1,2,3,5. I like to reorder them like this :
1,2,3,4. How can I achieve this ?

Any Django method or python code or sql code ?

Comment: Imagine that you have one million rows, that means for every delete on average 500k rows should be updated, and there can be foreign keys, so this can easily scale up to ten millions of rows. This means you probably can only perform 100-1000 such operations per second (given you have a quite fast server).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good idea at scale.  If you delete 1 record, let's say id=4 out of 1000 records.  Then you'd need to update 995 records after that.  So you'd bog down sql connection with constant updates.

And what you will do with all foreign keys?

I think the easier way to implement this would be to change the query to delete the 4th instance instead of locating it via id or pk.

Sorry for not directly answering the question as specified, but I'm hoping the extra context will help.

Comment: I also think this is not a good idea. Cause my database would be huge. Yeah you are right . But can you please elaborate this line. It seems to be not understandable to me :
'I think the easier way to implement this would be to change the query to delete the 4th instance instead of locating it via id or pk.'

Comment: What I am trying to point out is that its very seldom that you really have the use case where you delete pk=4 where the 4 is hard coded. But it sounds like that isn't the reason you want to keep the 4th instance in the data model to be pk=4 instead your concern is that you'll end up with non-sequential ids.  Or just a very high number of ids.  I don't think that is a concern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707072/what-is-the-biggest-id-number-that-autoincrement-can-produce-in-mysql